# How to compare CSS attributes

Tags: javascript, css

```
function switchVisibility(id){
     if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility === "visible"){
         document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
     } else {
         document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
     }
}
```

I'm trying to create a Javascript function that checks whether a CSS attribute is true or false. Based on the state of the attribute it will be changed. But it doesn't work and I'm not finding my mistake.

Comment: Is "comape" supposed to be "compare"?

Comment: Also you'll need to post more information. How exactly does it not work? Are there errors? Does *anything* happen? What does the HTML markup look like? How is the function called? What sort of debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Does your code run? Are there errors in the console? What if you put `console.log`s in your code in the logic? Does that reveal any issues?

Comment: try with `.style.display === "block"`

Comment: @Pointy that's why there is a `edit' button.... Especially to the light that @Pharagon has a reputation of 1.. I think that newcomers should be welcome..

Comment: @FabrizioMazzoni I might have edited if the spelling had been closer ("compre" or "compar") but as far as I know "comape" could have been a non-English word left alone by Google Translate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) function.

Here's how you could use it with your example:

```
function switchVisibility(id){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var cStyle = getComputedStyle(element);
    var visibility = cStyle.getPropertyValue("visibility");  
    element.style.visibility = visibility === "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

The reason simply checking for a property in [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) doesn't work is that `.style` only accounts for the CSS properties attached to the element's `style` attribute, excluding the styles it gets by default and via `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chrome. I checked your function and it works, except for the first time it executes. As far as I see it, the problem is in your `if`. You check whether the element's visible attribute is 'visible'. However, by default most of the programmers do not specify this attribute because browsers make elements visible by default. So, for this specific attribute for example, you should check whether it is empty:

`if(document.getElementById(id).style.visibility === "visible" || 
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility === "")`.

In addition, in order to make your code a bit cleaner, I think you better extract 'getting the element' into a variable.

Hope that solves your problem. :)

Answer (score -2):

Using a framework such as jQuery or zepto would allow you to use hasClass. That would look like:

```
if ($('#your-id').hasClass('visible')){
    // your code for when it's visible
}
else { 
    // your code for when it's hidden
}
```

Under the hood, jQuery writes that as

```
hasClass: function( selector ) {
    var className, elem,
        i = 0;

    className = " " + selector + " ";
    while ( ( elem = this[ i++ ] ) ) {
        if ( elem.nodeType === 1 &&
            ( " " + getClass( elem ) + " " ).replace( rclass, " " )
                .indexOf( className ) > -1
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is why things like jQuery and zepto exist - to give you more time thinking about your application instead of how to write things that have already been written.

Comment: Having the class "visible", whether you check it with jQuery or native JS, is unrelated to whether the effective value of the "visibility" property is "hidden" or "visible".

Comment: It is supposed that the OP doesn't know anything about jQuery. It is not asked for a jQuery solution as one can see in the tags. In this case there is no benefit doing it with jQuery.

Comment: That is why I provided how jQuery/zepto does what the OP is asking for. As for checking the CSS property versus a class - you should always manage your elements with classes, it's easier, cleaner, and more scalable. That is why all javascript front end frameworks use this principle.